# Can't add loading bar (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this problem:

I was trying to add a simple loading bar to my angular project, but somehow i can't get it to work.

I was trying to implement this one: http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/

I have installed it with "npm install angular-loading-bar" with succes. And in my angular module, it is set as a dependency.

```
angular.module('myAppRename.view5', ['ngRoute', 'angular-loading-bar'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/view5', {
        templateUrl: 'app/view5/view5.html',
        controller: 'View5Ctrl'
    });
}])
```

But somehow this makes my website crash, and with the developer tool opened, it get this error message:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myAppRename due to:    
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myAppRename.view5 due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angular-loading-bar due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'angular-loading-bar' is not available! You either misspelled     the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$injector/nomod?p0=angular-loading-bar
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you include angular-loading-bar js file in your index.html?

Comment: Just added: <script src="../node_modules/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js"></script> to index.html. But it is still the same.

Comment: Did you load it before you instantiate 'myAppRename'?

Comment: Yes i did. But it seems like a general problem to me, that i cant add anything else as a dependency without the browser will crash.

Comment: Can you provide more code, possibly on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure dependency library is loaded before Angular.

Try putting 
`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.7.1/loading-bar.min.js'></script>` in the very bottom of your `index.html`, before the `</body>` tag.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install it via **bower** `$ bower install angular-loading-bar`
2. Add following in index.html

   `<link rel='stylesheet' href="libs/angular-loading-bar/src/loading-bar.css" type='text/css' media='all' />
   <script type='text/javascript' src='libs/angular-loading-bar/src/loading-bar.js'></script>`
3. Add `'angular-loading-bar'` inside `angular.module` in app.js
4. Under `angular.module` add this

   `.config(['cfpLoadingBarProvider', function(cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
       cfpLoadingBarProvider.parentSelector = '#loading-bar-container';
       cfpLoadingBarProvider.spinnerTemplate = '<div><span class="fa fa-spinner"> Loading data...</div>';
     }])`
5. Call `loading-bar-container` ID in html view like this

   `<div id="loading-bar-container">`